# Javascript Virtual Machine

Tags: javascript, linux, debian, virtual-machine

I'm wondering if there is any `javascript virtual machine` you've used before or you have any ideas about !

I'm not talking about javascript engine for browsers like `V8` for `chrome`, I'm looking to execute javascript code on a linux server machine.

Thanks

Comment: As David said; V8 and other JS engines can be run outside of a browser.

Comment: Oppositely, Javascript Virtual Machine running Linux: http://bellard.org/jslinux/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be interested in [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: BTW: Node.JS is also based on V8.

Comment: Node.JS is a Event thingy wrapped around V8, not a JS engine itself. AFAIK it is for building network services, not executing arbitrary JS.

Comment: @David Dorward: Node.JS is a ready-made package whereas V8, SpiderMonkey and Rhino require a significant amount work to have them running independently as a Linux server application.

Answer (score 6):

[V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), [SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) and [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) can all run without a browser.